# Matlab figures: Which format to reuse in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have two scripts that produce some plots. I want to reuse those figures in another script, which will create subplots with the plots from the first script on the left-hand side, and plots from the second script on the right-hand side.

I tried to save the figures from the first scripts in tiff and then loading them in the last script, but the result is blurry (probably due to resizing). Which format should I use to save the figures with the first scripts?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101806-how-can-i-insert-my-matlab-figure-fig-files-into-multiple-subplots

Comment: If you are usingmatlab plots, save them as .fig. If you want to save things as images, dotn save matlab plots as jpg, do it as png.